# How to use right-Alt key instead of left-Alt key

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, i3

I have **Arch Linux** with **i3** window manager.

My left Alt key is broken and I want to assign left-alt tasks to right-alt. How i can do this?

> Now when I hold right alt and press a key, just types second language layout character.

Comment: Check the `loadkeys` man page (and from there the `keymaps` page). See also `xkeyboard-config`.

Comment: see this
[bind-alt-but-not-altgr-in-i3](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240235/bind-alt-but-not-altgr-in-i3)