# Bind alt but not altgr in i3

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, i3

I use Mod4 for most keybindings in i3, but I use Mod1 for this:

```
bindsym Mod1+a workspace a
bindsym Mod1+b workspace b
bindsym Mod1+c workspace c
bindsym Mod1+d workspace d
...
```

However this binds both alt and altgr, which is undesired since I use altgr+<letter> to type some characters.

xev says alt is Alt_L and altgr is Alt_R, but `bindsym Alt_L+a` doesn't work

Comment: Ultimately it depends on what xmodmap shows for mod1

Answer (score 5):

Ultimately it depends on what [xmodmap](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/xmodmap.1.html) shows for mod1.  For instance, if it shows that `Alt_L` and `Alt_R` are on the same modifier, you would have to move the latter to another (of the 5 available modifiers) to avoid conflict.

Here are a few pages giving examples:

- [Remapping Alt_R with xmodmap disable VC terminal switching](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=58145) shows an example where the user moved `Alt_R` from *mod1* to *mod4* (and ran into problems).  You should review the output from xmodmap before changing it.
- [xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap#Modifier_keys) on ArchLinux shows a detailed example manipulating modifiers.  To *move* a key, you must *add* it to one modifier and *clear* it from the other.

One pitfall in using `xmodmap` is that it does not always *know* the proper keycode for a key symbol (such as `Alt_R`).  When I encounter that, I can usually work around it by looking in the output from

```
xmodmap -pk
```

for the key *symbol*, and in the script, assign that keycode.  For example, on one machine `xmodmap -pk` shows

```
108         0xffea (Alt_R)  0x0000 (NoSymbol)       0xffea (Alt_R)
```

and using this script

```
keycode 108 = Alt_R
remove mod1 = Alt_R
add mod3 = Alt_R
```

changes the output from this:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

to this:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        Alt_R (0x6c)
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

(For this particular machine, the workaround is not needed).

Comment: So I made a file `.Xmodmap` containing `clear Mod1\nadd Mod1 = Alt_L` and ran `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` however it didn't change anything.

Comment: But you did not show the result of xmodmap before and after, to show what the change might have been.

Comment: What do you mean? The `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` command outputted nothing to stdout.

Comment: Without any options or parameters, `xmodmap` prints the current modifier map (like the `-pm` option). If you tell it to read a file, to set modifiers, it does not print the result at that time.

Comment: I restarted and took the output both before and after running `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`, it was http://pastebin.com/V07mRn3F both times.